# Method in class will not take arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python and I am just trying to make a simple class to test it out. I used the self argument while defining my method in the "Patient" class but I am still getting the "takes no arguments error" when I try to build. Here is the code I'm trying to run...

```
class Patient:
    def _init_(self,name,weight=0,LegLen=0):
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight
        self.LegLen = LegLen


Mark = Patient('Mark')
print(Mark.name)
```

then I get the error... 
    Mark = Patient('Mark')
TypeError: Patient() takes no arguments

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `_init_` should be spelled `__init__` (double underscores). Otherwise it's just a method like any other and not a constructor.

Comment: @MitchellLeefers: My pleasure. With some fonts, it's actually quite hard to see the difference as the two underscores are joined together and form a single line.